# R rolling cumprod

Tags: r, dplyr

My data has the monthly returns for securities with a maximum of 165 months ending in September 2016. I want to calculate three-year returns forward for each security from each starting point from Jan. 1, 2003 through Sept. 30 2013, but some of the securities come and go and I'm worried about survivor bias. To get around that, I need to calculate the average annual return over three years, which will give me a result I can use even if a security has fewer than 36 records beyond the given starting point. This is simple when I segregate the 37 records required to calculate the average annual return for a single security and starting point:

```
library(dplyr)

df <-
df %>%
arrange(date) %>%
mutate(cumProds = cumprod(1 + return))

avgAnnRet <- with(tail(df,1), cumProds^(12/nrow(df)))
```

But for each security, I could have as many as 129 starting points to calculate from, and I have thousands of securities. I've tried various iterations of rollapply and cumprod within dplyr groups, but I can't get any of them to work. Is it possible with a single statement (dplyr or other) to group by security and starting date and do rolling cumprod calculations. In my instance, of course, I would need it to return results whether there are 37 records or fewer.

I wrote a loop that will do the required subsetting and math, but it's obviously incredibly slow.

Comment: There are packages RcppRoll and roll that already do these things.

Comment: The function `RollingCompound` from the `RollingWindow` package does what you are asking for in a very straightforward and efficient way.

Comment: roll_prod from RcppRoll works almost perfectly, but it returns NA for groupings with fewer records than the window size. The documentation lists a "partial" argument that I'm guessing would deal with such issues, but that currently is unimplemented.

Answer (score 3):

Kevin Ushey, author of RccpRoll, was kind enough to give me a workaround since roll_prod will not return values for partial windows. It worked perfectly and was really fast on ~2 million records:

```
df %>%
arrange(secId, date) %>%
group_by(secId) %>%
mutate(product = as.numeric(rollapply(1 + return, 37, prod,
    partial = TRUE, align = "left")))
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where partial data was not acceptable (i.e. if only 36 of the 37 data points were available, then I wanted the product to be `NA`).  When I used Tom's `rollapply` idea with `partial = TRUE`, I got an error message like

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column `product` must be length 11 (the group size) or one, not 37
```

It turned out what was missing was `fill = NA`:

```
df %>% 
  arrange(secId, date) %>% 
  group_by(secId) %>% 
  mutate(product = rollapply(1 + return, 37, prod, fill = NA, partial = FALSE, align = "left"))
```